# changing values of selectOneMenu in JSF

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I am new to JSF and i am stuck at one place. I have one dropdown list which contains two items.

1. Bank
2. Cash

Now, if I select bank the other dropdown should populate items related to bank and if I select cash, cash items should be shown in 2nd dropdown.

How to do it in JSF? Where I have to make changes?

Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: where you get those data to fill dropdowns.?

Comment: Just work through some basic tutorials to get a firm grasp on the basic matters. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info Once you've concrete code and a concrete technical programming problem, you're always welcome to ask it here.

Comment: I am getting data from database MySQL

Comment: Can I use Javascript and add a method in it?

Comment: Better yet, write JSF code in such way that the right HTML/JS code is autogenerated. Or are you missing the whole point of JSF? Again, see the link in my previous comment. It contains a concrete example of populating a child menu.

Comment: I have read the example and implemented it but the problem is that it is not displaying specific items..All items are getting displayed :(

Comment: when I change parent, child should display specific items only..how to do this? cascading drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use primefaces to improve jsf development

```
 <p:selectOneMenu id="cboCountries" value="#{beanCountries.ValueSelected}" effect="fade">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="-1" /> //a default value
       <f:selectItems value="#{beanCountries.listOfCountries}" var="countries" itemLabel="#{countries.name}" itemValue="#{countries.id}"/>
       <p:ajax event="change" update="cboCities" listener="beanCountries.listCities()"/> //notice "update" refresh an especific DOM Element of an especific ID
 </p:selectOneMenu>

 <p:selectOneMenu id="cboCities" value="#{beanCities.ValueSelected}" effect="fade">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select City" itemValue="-1" /> //a default value
       <f:selectItems value="#{beanCities.listOfCities}" var="cities" itemLabel="#{cities.name}" itemValue="#{cities.id}"/> //this is when you want to put elements from DB or from an Array 
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

" is a special mark from primefaces, the event = "change" will invoke the you select an element from the first "ComboBox" then the property update will refresh the second comboBox, and the property "listener" will do the logical action of what you want to do, in this case the method "listCities()" will fill "listOfCities" with values from DB o Arrays.

So in jsf without primefaces will be like this:

```
<h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{beanCountries.ValueSelected}">
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="-1" /> //a default value
           <f:selectItems value="#{beanCountries.listOfCountries}" var="countries" itemLabel="#{countries.name}" itemValue="#{countries.id}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:selectOneMenu id="cboCities" value="#{beanCities.ValueSelected}">
               <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select City" itemValue="-1" /> //a default value
               <f:selectItems value="#{beanCities.listOfCities}" var="cities" itemLabel="#{cities.name}" itemValue="#{cities.id}"/> //this is when you want to put elements from DB or from an Array 
         </h:selectOneMenu>
         <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="beanCountries.listCities()"/>
</h:form>
```

this way is with a button (in jsf) and the action property will execute a java Method and then refresh the page. also this could be made by "ValueChangeListener" property of the selectOneMenu component

Comment: To avoid a major misconception: this is also possible with just standard JSF components. OP didn't mention anywhere that he is already using PrimeFaces. See also the link in the comment on the question.

Comment: As per your edit: how in earth did you completely miss the `<f:ajax>`? Why did you neglect to read JSF 2.x books/tutorials/resources and the link in the comment on the question?

Comment: you are right BalusC, f:ajax will be the solve of exactly he wants.